# How to include personal photo in email header

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to add a personalized picture so that it shows up in the upper right hand corner of my emails when I send them. I have added the picture to my contact information but it doesn't show up when I send emails.

Is there a way to achieve this in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The contact pictures are pictures the users assign to their contacts so they can recognize them. You can't control the picture shown on the receiving end.

If you're using an Exchange server and on Active Directory then [the network admin can assign a picture in AD](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ilvancri/archive/2009/11/17/upload-picture-in-outlook-2010-using-the-exchange-management-shell-exchange-2010.aspx) that will be used in Exchange/Outlook, but it will only be visible to the other users of your AD/Exchange environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this steps by uncheck the internet option -> Security `"Do not save encrypted pages to disk"` and restart the outlook application and also like to disable the option  `"show picture placeholder"` going through New message ->option dialogue -> Editor option -> in advance tab -> right side Display e-mail content.

Hope this helps.